# NoCredentialsError botocore.exceptions.NoCredentialsError: Unable to locate credentials even after passing credentials

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, docker, boto3, amazon-sqs

I'm working on sending messages to a SQS queue inside a Flask application.
I'm mimicing this SQS functionality in local using https://github.com/vsouza/docker-SQS-local.

I'm setting credentials for `boto3.client()` inside function.
When I run the function for sending messages directly in Pycharm, it is sending messages to SQS queue.

But when I dockerize this Flask application and call the endpoint which triggers this function, it is throwing error.

> raise NoCredentialsError botocore.exceptions.NoCredentialsError:
>   Unable to locate credentials

Here's the code for sending messages.

```
def send_mes():
    config = Config()
    sqs = boto3.client('sqs', aws_access_key_id=None, aws_secret_access_key=None,
                       endpoint_url=config.QUEUE_ENDPOINT_URL, region_name='default')
    feeder_queue = config.FEEDER_QUEUE

    def inside_fun():
        while True:
            resp = sqs.send_message(
                QueueUrl=feeder_queue,
                MessageBody=(
                    f'Sample message for Queue at {datetime.now()}.'
                )
            )
            print(resp)
            time.sleep(3)

    t1 = threading.Thread(target=inside_fun)
    t2 = threading.Thread(target=inside_fun)

    t1.start()
    t2.start()

    t1.join()
    t2.join()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    send_mes()
```

Please point out where am I making mistake?

Comment: aws_access_key_id=None, aws_secret_access_key=None ??

Comment: As I'm testing the SQS service in local using docker container on `localhost:9324`, I just set the keys to None which is working fine if I run the script directly.

Comment: So how are you expecting the docker container to have the correct credentials if your passing in None?

Comment: Yes. Because we are just connecting to `local SQS` service which doesn't need actual aws credentials and uses local queue endpoint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than passing the AWS credentials to the client directly in the code, I set the environment variables and it worked.

Comment: Can you tell exactly how did you do that?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/58814/how-do-i-add-environment-variables This is how I did it.